# VSCode Quick Fix : Fix using copilot is my only option

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I am programming in Dart/Flutter, using VSCode.

I also use Copilot, of course.

I love Copilot's auto suggest, but when VSCode highlights an error and I hover on it to "Quick Fix" the problem, the Copilot suggested fixes, in that situation, are rarely (if ever) helpful.

Unfortunately, increasingly it seems, "Fix using Copilot" is the only "Quick fix" option available.

[image: ![enter image description here]

**I want my other Quick Fix options back.**

And, I don't really want the Copilot options (but I certainly want to keep Copilots in-code suggestions).

I have tried doing `dart: restart analysis server` from the VSCode command pallet,
but in this case that is no longer working.

###### How in VSCode can I get my Quick Fix options back, and turn off the "Fix using Copilot" options ?

---

#### Update:

Results of running `Help : About` in the VSCode command pallet:

```
Version: 1.82.3
Commit: fdb98833154679dbaa7af67a5a29fe19e55c2b73
Date: 2023-10-02T11:06:17.496Z (3 wks ago)
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 24153832
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 22.4.0
```

#### Update 2:

Based on @starball's suggestions I did the following: Going back a significant version (and the auto fix suggestions disappeared), then going forward to the latest solution and disabling Copilot completely.
The result then was that were no quick fix solutions available.

[image]

I would have thought that it would have had a suggestion available to fix a "value could be null" error, but maybe I'm just misremembering how helpful this was??

Does VSCode have a Quick Fix suggestion for you if you access a bool that could be a var, without doing the null check?

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Does this happen in VS Code insiders or if you roll back to the previous minor release of VS Code? (Ex. I wonder if recent changes like https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/195353 caused breakages)